# How to get passport back from UK consulate while traveling to other countries?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, international-travel, delays

I am a US permanent resident applied for UK visa. I received email saying that visa has been granted and my documents will be shipped in 72 hours. It's been 8 days, I am still waiting.

My problem is this I am traveling to other countries before going to London which I already have visa and have flights booked but don't have my passport. I already emailed UK visa immigration international inquiry service but didn't get the specific answer, all they say is have patience and wait.

Can someone suggest how to get my passport back on time so I can travel to other countries? Please let me know if there is phone number to call.

Answer (score 1):

Notification emails issued from the British Consulate General in New York contain the shipping tracking number in the email title.

You can use this number to enquire after the current state of your passport.